# Then выполняется раньше When

Tags: javascript, cucumber

я имею код файл feature:

```
  Scenario: 1
    Given Start
    When Do something
    Then Show result
```

и js файл:

```js
Given(/^Start$/, function () {
    console.log("start")
});

When(/^Do something$/, function (className) {
     setTimout(()=>{
      let a=1+2
      console.log(1+2)      
     }, 1000)
});

Then(/^Show result$/, function () {
     console.log("end")       
});
```

Как мне переделать код чтобы увидеть 3 раньше чем еnd?

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Given(/^Start$/, function () {
    console.log("start")
});

When(/^Do something$/, async function (className) {
     let p = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
        resolve( 1+ 2);
      }, 2000);
   });
   console.log(p);
});

Then(/^Show result$/, function () {
     console.log("end")       
});
```

По таймингам  в консоли видно что прошло 2 секунды

Comment: Ascolon спасибо за ответ, для меня это работает.